# strict aliasing и реальные компиляторы

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Сразу же оговорюсь: я уважаю стандарт :)
*"Закон есть закон" (с) Фердинанд Пасторелли*

Тем не менее - насколько это серьезно в *реальной жизни*? Хочется посмотреть на конкретные примеры, где нарушение strict aliasing реально приводит к неприятностям, причем желательно не запутанные примеры с передачей трех разных указателей на одно и то же место в памяти в одну функцию, а что-то типа обнуления массива `char` через `long long`?

Еще раз прошу не подозревать в том, что я хочу получить ответ и на его основании наехать на стандарт :)

Comment: Нарывался на нечто подобное: http://rextester.com/COM19906
С char'ами такое не прокатит, естественно.

Comment: Последствия хорошо описаны в статье «[Про C++ алиасинг, ловкие оптимизации и подлые баги](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114117/)».

Comment: @Abyx Я же не спрашиваю, **что это такое**, это вопрос о другом.

Comment: единственное место где компиляторы  пока что избегают strict alising это  каламбуры типов через объединения (union), слишком часто используемые для работы с аппаратурой. очень много примеров с использованием memset/memezero

Answer (score 8):

Вот пример:

```
char const * test(char const * p_data)
{
    reinterpret_cast< int const * & >(p_data) += 1; // пропускаем 4 байта
    return(p_data);
}
```

`-O3`

> **mov** rax, rdi
>
> **ret**

`-O3 -fno-strict-aliasing`

> **lea** rax, [rdi+4]
>
> **ret**

[Online compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/Wdnt4Q)

Comment: Да, но стоит написать как `p_data = (char const*)((int const *)(p_data) + 1);` - и все становится на свои места... Я скорее к тому, что пример кажется достаточно надуманным. Но в любом случае спасибо!

Comment: @Harry Пример из реального проекта. А если написать `p_data = (char const*)((int const *)(p_data) + 1);`, то и нарушения strict aliasing не будет.

Comment: Почему же не будет? Есть доступ по указателю `int*` к данным типа `char`. Вполне себе нарушение.

Comment: @Harry В данном случае доступа по указателю `int *` к данным типа `char` нет. В исходном же примере алиасинг вставляет палки в колеса оттого, что действия производятся над исходным указателем, а не над временным.

Comment: Такая функция использовалась в реальном коде? Она имеет какие-то особые преимущества над чем-то вроде `p_data = pdata + sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @wololo Да, использовалась. Кажется в оригинальном коде преимущество было как раз в отсутствии двойного преобразования `void *` -> `target_type *` -> `void *`. Потом исходный указатель стал  `byte *` и сам код стал как вы и написали.

Comment: Изврат какой-то, просто издевательство над здравым смыслом (и поделом налетевшему на такую ошибку)