# Один элемент в нескольких двусвязных списках - вопросы безопасности эффективной реализации

Tags: c++, оптимизация, двусвязный-список, неопределённое-поведение, strict-aliasing

Иногда возникает ситуация, когда один объект должен являться элементом одновременно в нескольких двусвязных списках (например, это может быть объект окна или виджета в каком-нибудь оконном интерфейсе, которой одновременно может входить в список сортировки по Z для упорядоченной отрисовки, список группы виджетов для последовательного переключения между ними клавишей TAB, список дочерних окон родительского окна, и т.д...). Можно для этой задачи, конечно, использовать стандартные в C++ списки `std::list` с указателями или ссылками на соответствующие элементы. Однако в этом случае реализация окажется не очень эффективной, т.к. для добавления ссылки в каждый список будет происходить дополнительное выделение памяти под соответствующую запись списка, это помимо выделения памяти под сам объект. А хотелось бы, чтобы оператор `new` вызывался только один раз - для создания самого объекта, который бы потом добавлялся в списки с помощью простого связывания указателей.

В общем, моя идея в том, чтобы связывать элементы с помощью записей, которые являются полями самого класса-элемента. Списки этих записей классически закольцованы, т.е. указатель на следующую запись последнего элемента и указатель на предыдущую запись первого элемента указывают на сам класс-список. А класс-список, в свою очередь, "знает" смещение своих записей в классе-элементе, благодаря чему способен конвертировать указатель на запись в указатель на элемент и обратно путём вычитания или добавления смещения поля записи. Для облегчения понимания мною написанного привожу схему данной идеи:

```
                                                  +---------+    +---------+           +---------+
                                                  | ELEMENT |    | ELEMENT |           | ELEMENT |
                                                  |   ...   |    |   ...   |           |   ...   |
                                                  |         |    |         |           |         |
                              --> +-------+ ----> |+-------+| -> |+-------+| ->     -> |+-------+| -->
       +--- ...from last NODE1    | LIST1 |       || NODE1 ||    || NODE1 ||    ...    || NODE1 ||    to LIST1... ---+
       |                      <-- +-------+ <---- |+-------+| <- |+-------+| <-     <- |+-------+| <--               |
       |                                          |         |    |         |           |         |                   |
       |                      --> +-------+ ----> |+-------+| -> |+-------+| ->     -> |+-------+| -->               |
   +-->+    ...from last NODE2    | LIST2 |       || NODE2 ||    || NODE2 ||    ...    || NODE2 ||    to LIST2...    +-->+
   |   |                      <-- +-------+ <---- |+-------+| <- |+-------+| <-     <- |+-------+| <--               |   |
   |   |                             ...          |   ...   |    |   ...   |           |   ...   |                   |   |
   |   |                                          |         |    |         |           |         |                   |   |
   |   |                      --> +-------+ ----> |+-------+| -> |+-------+| ->     -> |+-------+| -->               |   |
   |   +--- ...from last NODEn    | LISTn |       || NODEn ||    || NODEn ||    ...    || NODEn ||    to LISTn... ---+   |
   |                          <-- +-------+ <---- |+-------+| <- |+-------+| <-     <- |+-------+| <--                   |
   |                                              +---------+    +---------+           +---------+                       |
   |                                                                                                                     |
   |                                                                                                                     |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Однако на пути реализации этой идеи стоит такая мерзкая штука, как **strict aliasing**, которую мне надо умудриться не нарушить, чтобы не получилось [вот так, как в прошлый раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105521/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-mingw-g)!

В правилах, если я правильно понял, есть два ключевых момента: 1) разрешается приводить указатель на что угодно к `char*` или `void*`, и `char*` или `void*` к указателю на что угодно; 2) разрешается приводить указатель на класс-родитель к указателю на класс-потомок и, соответственно, наоборот. Основываясь на них, я написал следующий код - основу в первом приближении для реализации таких "множественных" списков:

```
/*
 * File: List.h
 */

#ifndef List_h__included__
#define List_h__included__

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdexcept>

#ifndef INLINE
#define INLINE  __attribute__ ((always_inline)) inline
#endif


class CListNode;

/*
 * Base class for both: lists and nodes
 */

class CListBase
{
protected:
    union
    {
        CListNode*  m_pNext;
        CListNode*  m_pFirst;
    };
    union
    {
       CListNode*  m_pPrev;
       CListNode*  m_pLast;
    };

public:
    INLINE CListBase() {}
    INLINE CListBase(CListNode* pNext, CListNode* pPrev): m_pNext(pNext), m_pPrev(pPrev) {}
};


/*
 * The list node that's a field of the list element data class
 */

class CListNode: public CListBase
{
    friend class CListCommon;

public:
    INLINE bool dbg_is_linked() const
    {
#ifndef NDEBUG
        return m_pNext != NULL;
#else
        throw std::runtime_error("The debug check function was called not in the debug mode!");
#endif
    }

    INLINE void dbg_unlink()
    {
#ifndef NDEBUG
        m_pNext = NULL;
#endif
    }

    INLINE CListNode()                          {dbg_unlink();}
    INLINE CListNode& operator =(CListNode& r)  {dbg_unlink(); return *this;} 
    INLINE CListNode(CListNode&)                {dbg_unlink();} 
    INLINE ~CListNode()                         {assert (!dbg_is_linked());}

    INLINE CListNode* GetNext() const           {return m_pNext;}
    INLINE CListNode* GetPrev() const           {return m_pPrev;}
                                
    INLINE void InsertBefore(CListNode* pNode)
    {
        assert (!dbg_is_linked());
        assert (pNode && pNode->dbg_is_linked());
        CListNode* pPrev = pNode->m_pPrev;
        m_pNext = pNode;
        m_pPrev = pPrev;
        pPrev->m_pNext = this;
        pNode->m_pPrev = this;
    }

    INLINE void InsertAfter(CListNode* pNode)
    {
        assert (!dbg_is_linked());
        assert (pNode && pNode->dbg_is_linked());
        CListNode* pNext = pNode->m_pNext;
        m_pNext = pNext;
        m_pPrev = pNode;
        pNode->m_pNext = this;
        pNext->m_pPrev = this;
    }

    INLINE void CutSelf()
    {
        assert (dbg_is_linked());
        m_pNext->m_pPrev = m_pPrev;
        m_pPrev->m_pNext = m_pNext;
        dbg_unlink();
    }
};


/*
 * The list common class that implements the list's basical functionality
 */

class CListCommon: public CListBase
{
public:
    INLINE CListCommon(): CListBase((CListNode*)this, (CListNode*)this) {}
    INLINE ~CListCommon()           {assert(IsEmpty());}

    INLINE void dbg_force_empty()
    {
#ifndef NDEBUG
        m_pFirst = (CListNode*)this;
        //m_pLast = (CListNode*)this;
#endif
    }

    INLINE void dbg_unlink_all()
    {
#ifndef NDEBUG
        CListNode* pNode = m_pFirst;
        while (!IsEnd(pNode))
        {
            CListNode* pNext = pNode->m_pNext;
            pNode->dbg_unlink();
            pNode = pNext;
        }
        dbg_force_empty();
#endif
    }

    INLINE bool IsEmpty() const                 {return m_pFirst == (CListNode*)this;}
    INLINE bool IsEnd(CListNode* pNode) const   {return pNode == (CListNode*)this;}

    INLINE CListNode* GetFirst() const          {return m_pFirst;}
    INLINE CListNode* GetLast() const           {return m_pLast;}

    INLINE void Append(CListNode* pNode)
    {
        assert (pNode && !pNode->dbg_is_linked());
        pNode->m_pNext = (CListNode*)this;
        pNode->m_pPrev = m_pLast;
        m_pLast->m_pNext = pNode;
        m_pLast = pNode;
    }
};


/*
 * The final data-based list templated class
 */

template <class TData, CListNode TData::*nodeField>
class CList: public CListCommon
{
public:
    INLINE constexpr static size_t GetOffset()      {return (char*)&(((TData*)NULL)->*nodeField) - (char*)NULL;}
    INLINE static CListNode* GetNode(TData* pData)  {return (CListNode*)((char*)pData + GetOffset());}
    INLINE static TData* GetData(CListNode* pNode)  {return (TData*)((char*)pNode - GetOffset());}

    INLINE void Append(TData* pData)                {CListCommon::Append(GetNode(pData));}
};

//macro for convenient declaration of the list variable
#define LIST_TYPE(TData, nodeField) CList<TData, &TData::nodeField>


#endif //List_h__included__
```

А вот программа для тестирования/демонстрации того, как работает идея:

```
/*
 * File: main.cpp
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "List.h"


/*
 * The test data class for testing the lists' functionality
 */

class CTestData
{
    std::string     m_strName;
    int             m_num;

public:
    CListNode       node1;
    CListNode       node2;

public:
    INLINE CTestData(const char* pcszName, int num): m_strName(pcszName), m_num(num) {}

    void print()
    {
        printf("(\"%s\":%d)", m_strName.c_str(), m_num);
    }
};


/*
 * Templated function: prints the list content
 */

template <class TList>
__attribute__((noinline,noclone)) void print_list(TList& rList, const char* pcszPromt)
{
    printf("%s:  ", pcszPromt);

    for (CListNode* pNode = rList.GetFirst(); !rList.IsEnd(pNode); pNode = pNode->GetNext())
    {
        rList.GetData(pNode)->print();
        printf(" ");
    }

    puts("");
}


/*
 * main: testing the lists
 */

int main()
{
    //tested elements
    CTestData t1("A",1), t2("B",2), t3("C",3);

    //tested lists
    LIST_TYPE(CTestData, node1) list1;
    LIST_TYPE(CTestData, node2) list2;

    //linking list1
    list1.Append(&t1);
    list1.Append(&t2);
    list1.Append(&t3);

    //linking list2
    list2.Append(&t3);
    list2.Append(&t2);
    list2.Append(&t1);

    print_list(list1, "List1");
    print_list(list2, "List2");
    puts("");

    printf("Something insert and cut...\n\n");

    //new tested elements
    CTestData t4("ab",12), t5("D",5);

    t4.node1.InsertBefore(&t2.node1); //insert t4 before t2 in the list1
    t2.node2.CutSelf();               //cut t2 from the list2
    t5.node2.InsertAfter(&t1.node2);  //insert t5 after t1 in the list2

    print_list(list1, "List1");
    print_list(list2, "List2");
    puts("");

    //unlink all nodes in the debug mode (to avoid asserts)
    list1.dbg_unlink_all();
    list2.dbg_unlink_all();
    return 0;
}
```

А вот результат программы, который говорит о том, что всё вроде работает:

```
List1:  ("A":1) ("B":2) ("C":3)
List2:  ("C":3) ("B":2) ("A":1)

Something insert and cut...

List1:  ("A":1) ("ab":12) ("B":2) ("C":3)
List2:  ("C":3) ("A":1) ("D":5)
```

В общем, если я правильно понял (в общих чертах) strict aliasing, то мой код их вроде бы не нарушает, и его со спокойной душой можно развивать и использовать. Или нарушает? Меня всё ещё не покидают сомнения, не закралось ли тут где неопределённое поведение? Не подставит ли мне оптимизатор подношку однажды снова? Насколько надёжна такая реализация с точки зрения компиляции и оптимизации?

Comment: *"идея в том, чтобы связывать элементы с помощью записей, которые являются полями самого класса-элемента"* - это называется интрузивные контейнеры, и уже давно реализовано, например в boost.intrusive. *"если я правильно понял, есть два ключевых момента..."* - описываемое далее вообще мимо strict aliasing. В реализации творится какая-то вакханалия, например `(char*)&(((TData*)NULL)->*nodeField) - (char*)NULL` - мало того, что `NULL` и с-style касты, но тут сходу разыменовывается нулевой указатель с последующей гарантированно невалидной операцией разности.

Comment: @user7860670 почему вакханалия? `NULL` я использую по привычке и лени, потому что это короче `std::nullptr`. Далее, он тут не разыменовывается в том контексте, что по нему *не происходит* обращение. Его тип `void*` приводится к другим типам, что вроде как не запрещено. И с каких пор разность указателей - невалидная операция? Может где-то написано, что `NULL` или `nulptr` запрещено приводить к другим типам указателей?

Comment: *"по привычке и лени, потому что это короче"* - без комментариев... `std::nullptr` - нет же такого в языке, есть ключевое слово `nullptr` (который не эквивалентен `NULL`) и тип `std::nullptr_t`. *"он тут не разыменовывается"* - нет, нулевой указатель разыменовывается сразу после каста `((TData*)NULL)->*`. Поведение разности указателей определено только при соблюдении некоторых условий, произвольно что-то кастовать и вычитать не получится.

Comment: user7860670 да, с nulptr_t я спутал чутка. Ну хорошо, какие ещё есть способы получить смещение поля класса? Безопасные и не вызывающие предупреждения компилятора?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof Хотя и не универсальный. Тот же буст для такого использует ABI-специфическую магию.

Comment: [Вот эта реализация](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h) широко используется в Линуксе (в частности, в kernel)

Comment: В своих программах я обычно использую ту же идею (указатели на указатели), но более ограниченный набор макросов -- init_head, is_empty_list, add, remove, insert_list, container_of

Comment: @avp спасибо, изучу как-нибудь на досуге. Может почерпну новых идей.

Comment: @user7860670 стандартный макрос `offsetof`, к сожалению, не работает с полями-"указателями", которые передаются шаблону в качестве параметра. Во всяком случае, у меня не получилось его использовать.

Answer (score 0):

И так, самым критикуемым местом в моей реализации оказался метод `GetOffset()`, который возвращает смещение поля узла списка в классе. Потому, что в его теле присутствует разыменование указателя `nullptr`, что хоть и работает, но с точки зрения стандарта приводит к неопределённому поведению. Что ж, вот моя попытка избавиться от разыменования `nullptr` в этом методе:

```
template <class TData, CListNode TData::*nodeField>
class CList: public CListCommon
{
public:
    //redesigned method without using of nullptr
    INLINE constexpr static size_t GetOffset()
    {
        char tmp[sizeof(TData)] = {0,}; //"initialize" to exclude another supposed formal UB
        return (char*)&(((TData*)tmp)->*nodeField) - tmp;
    }

    INLINE static CListNode* GetNode(TData* pData)  {return (CListNode*)((char*)pData + GetOffset());}
    INLINE static TData* GetData(CListNode* pNode)  {return (TData*)((char*)pNode - GetOffset());}

    INLINE void Append(TData* pData)                {CListCommon::Append(GetNode(pData));}
};
```

Результат получился тот же самый. Массив `tmp` оказался выкинут и метод `GetOffset()` посчитан на этапе компиляции/оптимизации - что и требовалось.

Буду благодарен за очередную порцию критики, а так же за освещение других вероятных проблем в коде...

Comment: Ну, концептуально проблема никуда не делась. Та сущность, на которую указывает указатель `(TData*)tmp`, не является живым объектом типа `TData` (как и в случае с нулевым указателем). Рассмотрим чуть более простой пример. Пусть есть такой код: `((TData*)tmp)->field_name;` (т.е. просто обращаемся к полю класса по имени, но не читаем и не пишем значение, даже адрес не берём). Этот код можно переписать так: `reinterpret_cast<TData&>(tmp).field_name;` Можно ли обращаться к полю `field_name`, если объект по адресу `tmp` отличен от `Tdata`? Нельзя, см. [expr.ref/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#8).

Comment: Особенно обратите на пример кода по ссылке, особенно на строку `reinterpret_cast<B&>(d).j; // undefined behavior`. Аналогичная ситуация с указателем-на-член. См. [expr.mptr.oper/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mptr.oper#4). Там нет примера кода, но сама формулировка аналогичная. P.S. 1) Не следует использовать двойные подчёркивания в идентификаторах. [lex.name/3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3.1). 2) Возможно, лучше для буфера использовать `unsigned char`, т.к. для него стандарт даёт больше гарантий. 3) Следует соблюдать требования по выравниванию: `alignas(TData) unsigned char tmp...;`.

Comment: @wololo понятно. Но тогда получается, что вариант с разыменованием nullptr погоды не сделает, раз хоть так UB, хоть так. А вот про двойные подчёркивания я вообще в недоумении с разработчиков стандарта. Ладно, если бы идентификаторы только с начальными двойными подчёркиваниями зарезервировали. Но чтобы вообще запретить их использовать...