# Выражение должно быть допустимо для изменения левосторонним значением

Tags: c++

```
PVOID trampoline = (PVOID )1; //для примера присвоил рандомное значение
((PBYTE)trampoline)++; //тут ошибка (Выражение должно быть допустимо для изменения левосторонним значением)
```

Почему такая ошибка, ведь мы сначала преобразовали наш указатель к указателю на BYTE, после чего инкрементируем?
Причем в чисто сишном компиляторе все нормально компилируется.

Comment: Так а что вы хотите менять? Если сам указатель - то `(*(PBYTE*)&trampoline)++;`/ Если значение по этому адресу - `(*(PBYTE)trampoline)++;`. *"По-моему, так." (с) Пух*

Comment: @Harry а почему такая запись неверна? Ведь это то же самое по сути. Если бы мы указатель объявили как PBYTE, то все без ошибок было

Comment: Потому что это было бы lvalue - переменная. А `(PBYTE)trampoline` - это значение указателя, но не он сам. Просто значение, которое не может выступать в качестве ссылки.

Comment: *"Причем в чисто сишном компиляторе все нормально компилируется"* - [ничего подобного](https://godbolt.org/z/Tqxx69no3).

Comment: @Harry Мне кажется, что в таком случае будет нарушение strict aliasing.

Comment: @user7860670 Откровенно говоря, именно поэтому и написал свое пресловутое *"по-моему, так"* :) Не знаю. Это такой темный угол - strict aliasing - что врубиться, что можно, что нет - я никак не могу его *понять*, только что вызубрить наизусть... а с точки зрения практики мне кажется, что его опасность преувеличена. По крайней мере, ни разу не сталкивался с проблемами из-за этого...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

стандарт :

> 7.6.3  Explicit type conversion (cast notation)
>
> The result of the expression (T) cast-expression is of type T. The
> result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue
> reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference
> to object type; otherwise the result is a prvalue.  [Note 1 : If T is
> a non-class type that is cv-qualified, the cv-qualifier s are
> discarded when determining the type of the resulting prvalue; see 7.2.
> — end note]

перевод :

> 7.6.3  Явное преобразование типов (приведенная нотация)
>
> Результат приведения выражения (T) имеет тип T. Результатом является
> значение lvalue, если T является типом ссылки lvalue или ссылкой
> rvalue на тип функции, и значение xvalue, если T является ссылкой
> rvalue на тип объекта; в противном случае результатом является
> значение prvalue.  [Примечание 1 : Если T-тип, не относящийся к
> классу, который квалифицируется cv, квалификатор s cv отбрасывается
> при определении типа результирующего значения prvalue; см. 7.2. —
> конец примечания]

Приведение на объект даёт **новый** временный объект. Временный объект это не **lvalue**. А ссылка или `(*ptr)` будет **lvalue** после приведения типа. И её можно будет менять.

```
# include <cstdint>
# include <iostream>
typedef void * PVOID ;
typedef uint8_t * PBYTE ;
typedef uint8_t BYTE ;
BYTE arr[]={0,0,0};
PVOID trampoline = (PVOID )(&arr[0]);
int main(){
    // тут была ошибка (Выражение должно быть допустимо для изменения левосторонним значением)
    PBYTE && tmp = ((PBYTE)trampoline);
    tmp ++ ;
    std::cout<<"trampoline = "<<trampoline<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"tmp = "<<(void*)tmp<<std::endl;
    (*(PBYTE*)&trampoline)++;
    std::cout<<"trampoline = "<<trampoline<<std::endl;
    ((PBYTE&)trampoline)++;
    std::cout<<"trampoline = "<<trampoline<<std::endl;
}
```

=>

```
trampoline = 0x404191
tmp = 0x404192
trampoline = 0x404192
trampoline = 0x404193
```

---

*Справочник по **L**eft-value **R**ight-value :*

```
variable = LValue
& variable = RValue
(* (any pointer)) = LValue
((T)(any value)) = RValue
(*(T*)(any pointer)) = LValue
((T&)(any link)) - LValue
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что в `(*(PBYTE*)&trampoline)++;` будет нарушение strict aliasing.

Comment: Был указатель на байт `1` , стал указатель на байт `2`. Где тут стрикт? @user7860670

Comment: `&trampoline` - указатель на на указатель void, `(PBYTE*)` кастует его в указатель на указатель на byte, разыменование - UB.

Comment: Стандарт уточняет, что грубая смена типа указателя A* -> B* -> A*. Не приведёт к проблемам. Осталось только спросить у указателя `1` - а правильный ли ты (можешь ли указывать на байт?). В примере эта единица всего-лишь пример. @user7860670

Comment: Тут совсем не `A* -> B* -> A*`, тут `A* -> B* -> разыменование B*`

Comment: Это у автору вопроса будет проблема. Правильно, ли он приводит типы. Вопрос был про **rvalue** <-> **lvalue** . @user7860670

Comment: У автора код должен выдавать ошибку компиляции, а вот ваш код в ответе - это проблема.

Comment: Так нет проблем.

Comment: `uint8_t ran = 1 ; PVOID trampoline = (PVOID ) & ran ; ` - а так нет проблем ? @user7860670

Comment: Хм, вы случаем предыдущий комментарий не удаляли? А то получается что я сначала ответил, а потом пришел вопрос.

Comment: Кстати я вспомнил, что был вопрос про strict aliasing, где я приводил похожий пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749685/strict-aliasing-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b

Comment: Хватит критики, всем всё понятно. @user7860670